# How to process secondary sourse links via django views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend, referrals

Let's say I have the following home.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon-32x32.png' %}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href"/stylesheet_url">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and urls look like that:

```
urls = [
   path('home/', home)
]
```

and home view is:

```
def home(request):
   return render(request, 'home.html')
```

how should the any-referral view and any-referral url look like, so I could process request that uses any referral from inside of any resourse?

The Idea for url is that if I firstly specify all the concreate urls, then the last url in urls could be matching any url left. But the main problem seems that the veiw does not trigger on any url pattern (currently my everymatching url looks like `path('<path:referral>', any_refferal)`. Also I suspect that there stands a different mechanism behind using referrals from inside of page, compared to one that that processes the page

Comment: What do you mean by "any referral" ? What is a referral ?

Comment: I mean src or href in one word